# Problem Keyboard hide after write one char in TextInput (textinput inside Flatlist Header)

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist, react-native-textinput, lost-focus

i spent two days on this problem , the problem is :

when i placed a TextInput inside a Flatlist , **the behavior of the TextInput Changed , the Keyboard lose focus after every character writed.**

Version
React-native : 0.63.2
react : 16.13.1,
react-dom : 16.13.1,
expo : ~42.0.1,

Steps to reproduce

- i reated a State Variable called ==> [inputSearch, setInputSearch]
- i wrote a textinput inside the ListHeaderComponent of Flatlist

**--->  The problem is : After every Character pressed in Keyboard the Keyboard Hide**

State declaration :

```
const [inputSearch, setInputSearch] = useState(null);
```

TextInput is inside Flatlist :

```
    <View style={styles.container}>
    <StatusBar
         backgroundColor="#11131B"
         barStyle="light-content"
    />

    <View style={{width: '100%', flex: 1 , backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 5}}>

        <FlatList 
            contentContainerStyle={{alignItems: 'center',paddingHorizontal: 20}}
            keyExtractor={(item) => (Object.keys(item).length === 0) ? "" : item.id.toString()}
            width= {width}
            numColumns={2}
            ListHeaderComponent={() =>
                <View  style={{flexDirection:'column',justifyContent:'space-between'}}>

                   <Text style={{color:Colors.dark1, fontSize:14, marginBottom: 5}}>Search :</Text>
                   <TextInput style={styles.input} value={inputSearch} onChangeText={setInputSearch} placeholder="Username"/>

                </View>
            }
            data={SIMPLE_DATA}
            renderItem={renderItemRow}
        >

        </FlatList>
    </View>

  <View>
```

Comment: i dont face this problem when i placed the TextInput outside Flatlist

Comment: That's because everytime you call `setInputSearch` the FlatList is re-rendered, and with that is re-rendered the ListHeaderComponent too since you're passing it in an inline function. You should extract the ListHeaderComponent in a standalone component

Comment: i just Searched about "standalone component" and i can't find any Doc about it.

What i understand is to declare a new arrow function and place it in "ListHeaderComponent" , i just did it but i the problem didn't solve yet

`const HeaderFlatList() => (... Cotent Header )`

Comment: and i called it in Flatlist like that :

`ListHeaderComponent={HeaderFlatlist}`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm going to expand what I wrote on the comment since that was written quickly and not clear enough.

Let's consider the following as a starting point (I stripped off useless information):

```js
function YourComponent() {
  const [inputSearch, setInputSearch] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#11131B" barStyle="light-content" />

      <View>
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={() => (
            <>
              <Text>Search :</Text>
              <TextInput
                value={inputSearch}
                onChangeText={setInputSearch}
                placeholder="Username"
              />
            </>
          )}
          data={[]}
          renderItem={() => <View />}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Every time you call `setInputSearch` the component is rendered again, but this means that the arrow function you are passing inline inside ListHeaderComponent will be called every time and the content will be created again (the keyboard is closed because the input where the focus was on doesn't exist anymore, since it's been replaced by a new one).

How can you solve this? ListHeaderComponent accepts both constructors and ReactElement, so you either pass a ReactElement or create a "standalone" component (no specific meaning, it's just a component on its own, not inside another component).

---

Here are a couple of solutions:

1. ReactElement example (notice that the component is passed directly, there is no function in ListHeaderComponent; you can also extract this as another component if you want):

```js
function YourComponent() {
  const [inputSearch, setInputSearch] = useState('');

  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#11131B" barStyle="light-content" />

      <View>
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={
            <>
              <Text>Search :</Text>
              <TextInput
                value={inputSearch}
                onChangeText={setInputSearch}
                placeholder="Username"
              />
            </>
          }
          data={[]}
          renderItem={() => <View />}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}
```

2. Standalone component (passing the constructor to ListHeaderComponent):

```js
function YourComponent() {
  return (
    <View>
      <StatusBar backgroundColor="#11131B" barStyle="light-content" />

      <View>
        <FlatList
          ListHeaderComponent={ListHeaderComponent}
          data={[]}
          renderItem={() => <View />}
        />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

function ListHeaderComponent() {
  const [inputSearch, setInputSearch] = useState('');

  return (
    <>
      <Text>Search :</Text>
      <TextInput
        value={inputSearch}
        onChangeText={setInputSearch}
        placeholder="Username"
      />
    </>
  );
}
```

but this wouldn't allow you to use the inputSearch value in YourComponent.

---

I hope this helps clear things out.

Comment: Thanks A lot , now I understand why The Keyboard Lose Focus .

but , is there any Solution where i can use my state  "inputSearch" inside the main Component "YourComponent"

Comment: It’s the first solution example, the one with ReactElement. After “Here are a couple of solutions:” I put two different solutions for the same problem, and the first keeps inputSearch inside YourComponent

Comment: I added numbers to avoid confusion

Comment: Thanks a lot Giovanni , its Worked .

Comment: i really appreciate your Help, because i was stuck on this problem for 3 days

Answer (score 0):

you can also try rendering component directly without call back function like this

```js
<FlatList
  ...
  ListHeaderComponent={
    <Searchbar placeholder="Поиск" onChangeText={query => {this.setState({ firstQuery: query });}} value={firstQuery} style={{ margin: 16, marginBottom: 0 }}/>
  }
/>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).